# Comunicación serial ESP32 (micropython)

Tags: python, serialport, micropython

Tengo un proyecto, necesito que la ESP32 mande información por medio del serial, para que un programa lo recepcióne (un codigo lenguaje python) y base a la inf. del sensor haga una acción, necesito que envie la informacion a otro puerto y que el codigo python, se coenecte al puerto, para ejecutar una accion.

**Codigo de micropython**

```
from time import sleep


uart_com5 = UART(2, 9600)  
uart_com5.init(9600, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1)
while True:
    
    sensor_value = 123  # Esto sería el valor leído del sensor en tu código real
    
    uart_com5.write(str(sensor_value) + '\n')
    print('hola')
   
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Quizás respondo muy tarde, pero ojalá le sirva a otro usuario.

Ya que estás utilizando el puerto serial por defecto, por lo que asumo que quieres leer los valores mediante un cable uUSB, primero debes detectar que puerto estás utilizando:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
port = list(list_ports.comports())
for p in port:
    print(p.device)
```

Ya teniendo el ID del puerto, tan solo lee las líneas enviadas con `serial.Serial`:

```
while True: # o para leer n líneas: for i in range(n)
    with serial.Serial('rutaPuerto', 9600, timeout=1) as ser:
        line = ser.readline()
```

Luego de leer la línea, puedes almacenarla directamente en una lista, aunque te recomiendo que envíes un diccionario o un json desde el ESP32, para ir armando la base de datos de forma más ordenadas. En el caso del primero, puedes utilizar la librería `ast`, almacenar el diccionario en una lista y luego crear un dataframe para guardar los datos. Algo como:

```
import serial
import ast
import pandas as pd

from serial.tools import list_ports
port = list(list_ports.comports())
for p in port:
    print(p.device)

l = []

while True:
    with serial.Serial('rutaPuerto', 9600, timeout=1) as ser:
        line = ser.readline()
        try:
            dic = ast.literal_eval(line.decode('utf-8'))
            dic = dict(sorted(dic.items()))
            l.append(dic)
        except:
            pass

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Ahora, la estructura `while True` leerá indefinidamente. Puedes configurar algún carácter para frenar el bucle.